# Security in Headless Woocommerce App REST API

Tags: rest, authentication, woocommerce-rest-api

I am creating an application that receives an object with variables from the backend, after which it works like a SPA.
At the stage of receiving data that will be transferred to the frontend, O.Auth1.0a or basic authentication is used, using api keys. At this point, I think it's safe to use keys, and I'm using keys, such as a user with a shop manager role.
This role allows you to make all sorts of requests, such as receiving products, placing orders.
My question is, how can I solve the problem of doing the same requests on the client side - since even an authorized user (the role of customer) does not have the ability to make them.

What are my ideas and questions related to them:

1. Extensions of possible customer permissions - providing the ability to receive products and place orders - in response to such questions, it is stipulated that this is unacceptable.
   I have less doubts about post requests for receiving products (it seems that there is no confidential information in the product data), but there are more concerns about creating orders.
   At the moment I have a shopping cart working thanks to the JWT Authentication plugin, in the same way I was able to receive products when I granted permission to receive them using another plugin.
2. Transferring the manager's api keys to the client.
   Will the keys remain secret if passed to an environment variable?
   Or maybe transfer the keys encrypted?
   (Actually, I don't know much about this and would be happy to get resources and articles where you can read about this)